# Slide with javascript shows a modal box but not stops the slider

Tags: javascript, html

I made a javascript slide but i would like to make it stop when I click on a link inside one of the slides that opens a modal box, and after a few seconds continue to the other slide or click in the circles under the slides to keep watching the other slides. Do you have any idea how can i make it? I'm totally new in javascript and this is still hard for me, thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide more information about how you try to create a slider (or carousel), which technologies you use and so on.

Comment: Sorry, but don't know how to answer... I'm new to this web site development and used a slider i found on the internet...

Comment: Ok, but which one? Have you used Bootstrap, any other framework, or have you just copied code?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Creaticode/pen/xIfmw I copied this and I changed my images and also add a modal box i found in w3school http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: So, you want to open a modal that is showing the current image in fullscreen?

Comment: You are sure you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: I want to stop the slider when i click in one of the h2 tags where i added a button to open a modal box. 
I have this Jquery
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: Let us continue the error research in a chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114435/slide-with-javascript-shows-a-modal-box-but-not-stops-the-slider

Comment: Can't use cause i need 20 reputation...

Comment: Ok. So can you please provide your current code?

Comment: How can i show it?

Comment: You can copy your code into the question.